# Trying to create a descriptive table, facing difficulties with alignment

Tags: tables, longtable

```
Here is the code written for the same, I've also attached the image of the output. Please suggest the necessary changes.



\documentclass[landscape, 12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[table, svgnames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage[a4paper, landscape, margin=1cm,]{geometry}
    
    \usepackage{makecell, cellspace, caption}
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{2pt}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}
    \usepackage{array}
    \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
    \begin{document}
    
           
            \begin{longtable}{| L {5 cm} | L{4cm} | L{5cm} | L{2.5cm} | L{1.5cm} | L{2cm} |}
                \hline
                \rowcolor{Gainsboro!60}
                \makecell{Source of \\ information \\ (reference) 
      } & \makecell{Method of  \\ identification}  & \makecell{The consumer’s strengths \\ to address these issues.} & \makecell{Consumer \\ and Nursing \\ Interventions} & \makecell{Person/s \\ Responsible} & \makecell{Timeframe}\\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \\
    \\
    \\
    \\
      “A Novel Event Detection \\ Method Using PMU Data \\ with High Precision”\\ by Mingjian Cui,\\ Jianhui Wang, Jin Tan,\\ Anthony R. Florita, and \\ Yingchen Zhang, published \\ in IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON \\POWER SYSTEMS, 2018
      %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     & This paper develops a new method of event detection using dynamic programming-based SDT (DPSDT) and compares it with the Wavelet-based event detection (WED) technique. It gives the complete algorithm of the DPSDT technique and compares various events it could detect with sufficient graphs and figures.
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     & a.To reduce dimensionality of original streaming PMU data, islanding detection,
     b.compress critical disturbance info of PMU 
    c. locate power system event, 
    d. to select the best set of features of the disturbance types in the time-frequency domain, 
    e. discrete samples of collected PMU data, 
    f. assess the power system disturbance by using wide-area post disturbance records
    to identify events and characterize their features.
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     & 1.PMU
    
       2.PMU 
     and smart meter
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      30-120 times per sec
       \\
               \hline
               
            \end{longtable}
         
    \end{landscape}
    \end{document}
```

[image: Reference output]

Comment: ` “A Novel Event Detection \\ ` ends the table row at that point, you don't say what output you want but don't you just want to delete that `\\ `  and the  other ones on that line?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely delete all those `\\` (double backslash) in the first column.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[table, svgnames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[a4paper, landscape, margin=1cm,]{geometry}

\usepackage{makecell, cellspace, caption}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{2pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\usepackage{enumitem,ragged2e}
\newlist{myenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenumerate,1]{label=\alph*.,nosep,wide=0pt,
          before={\begin{minipage}{\hsize}\RaggedRight},
          after={\end{minipage}}}

\begin{document}
       
\begin{longtable}{| L{5cm} | L{4cm} | L{5cm} | L{2.5cm} | L{2cm} | L{2cm} |}
\hline
\rowcolor{Gainsboro!60}
\makecell{Source of \\ information \\ (reference) } & 
\makecell{Method of  \\ identification} & 
\makecell{The consumer’s strengths \\ to address these issues.} & 
\makecell{Consumer \\ and Nursing \\ Interventions} & 
\makecell{Person/s \\ Responsible} & 
\makecell{Timeframe}\\
\hline
\endhead

“A Novel Event Detection Method Using PMU Data with High Precision,” by Mingjian Cui, Jianhui Wang, Jin Tan, Anthony R. Florita, and Yingchen Zhang, published in IEEE Transactions on Power Systems, 2018

& This paper develops a new method of event detection using dynamic programming-based SDT (DPSDT) and compares it with the Wavelet-based event detection (WED) technique. It gives the complete algorithm of the DPSDT technique and compares various events it could detect with sufficient graphs and figures.

& \begin{myenumerate}
\item \strut To reduce dimensionality of original streaming PMU data, islanding detection,
\item compress critical disturbance info of PMU 
\item locate power system event, 
\item to select the best set of features of the disturbance types in the time-frequency domain, 
\item discrete samples of collected PMU data, 
\item assess the power system disturbance by using wide-area post disturbance records to identify events and characterize their features.\strut
\end{myenumerate}

 & 1.~PMU

   2.~PMU and smart meter, 30--120 times per sec
 & &
\\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!
But the issue now that is happening is the font size is too small and the table does not fit the entire page, (I tried increasing the font size)

Comment: @MudassirShaikh - Please provide more information about what you're doing. (Sorry, but my mind-reading skills are simply worthless.)

Comment: I want to fit the table scaled to the entire page size.

Comment: The one possibility that I see is by increasing the font size. @Mico

Comment: @MudassirShaikh - May I suggest you post a new query, with all information needed to handle your new use case? Thanks.

Comment: @Mico- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/635316/i-want-this-table-to-fit-the-entire-page-in-latex

Answer (score 0):

Probably to late for OP but it may be helpful for some else ...

By use of `tabularray` package and its `longtblr` table, use of the `booktabs` package rules and remove vertical ones, use `enumerate` list as defined in the `enumitem` package, your table can be  as is shown below:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe,
            a4paper, landscape, margin=1cm,]{geometry}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[svgnames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, varwidth}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtblr}{\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=*, nosep, itemsep=1pt}}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\DefTblrTemplate{capcont}{default}{}
\begin{longtblr}[
    entry=none,     % <---
    label=none,     % <---
                ]{colsep = 4pt,
                 colspec = {*{3}{X[2.5,j]}
                                 X[1.5,l]
                            *{2}{X[1,l]}
                            },
                 cells   = {font=\small\linespread{0.84}\selectfont},
                 row{3-Z}= {abovesep=9pt},
                 row{1}  = {c, m, bg=Gainsboro!60},
                 stretch = -1,  %<--- remove extra space above and below lists
                                % with nosep option; doc p.51 tabularray
                 measure = vbox,
                 rowhead = 1
                 }
    \toprule
Source of information (reference)
    &   Method of identification   
        &   The consumer’s strengths to address these issues. 
            &   Consumer and Nursing Interventions 
                &   Person/s Responsible 
                    &   Timeframe       \\
    \midrule
“A Novel Event Detection Method Using PMU Data with High Precision” by Mingjian Cui, Jianhui Wang, Jin Tan, Anthony R. Florita, and  Yingchen Zhang, published in IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON POWER SYSTEMS, 2018
    &   This paper develops a new method of event detection using dynamic programming-based SDT (DPSDT) and compares it with the Wavelet-based event detection (WED) technique. It gives the complete algorithm of the DPSDT technique and compares various events it could detect with sufficient graphs and figures.
        &   \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.] 
        \item   To reduce dimensionality of original streaming PMU data, islanding detection,
        \item   compress critical disturbance info of PMU
        \item   locate power system event,
        \item   to select the best set of features of the disturbance types in the time-frequency domain,
        \item   discrete samples of collected PMU data,
        \item   assess the power system disturbance by using wide-area post disturbance records
        to identify events and characterize their features.
            \end{enumerate}
            &   \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
            \item   PMU
            \item   PMU and smart meter 30-120 times per sec
                \end{enumerate}
                &   &   \\
“A Novel Event Detection Method Using PMU Data with High Precision” by Mingjian Cui, Jianhui Wang, Jin Tan, Anthony R. Florita, and  Yingchen Zhang, published in IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON POWER SYSTEMS, 2018
    &   This paper develops a new method of event detection using dynamic programming-based SDT (DPSDT) and compares it with the Wavelet-based event detection (WED) technique. It gives the complete algorithm of the DPSDT technique and compares various events it could detect with sufficient graphs and figures.
        &   \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
        \item   To reduce dimensionality of original streaming PMU data, islanding detection,
        \item   compress critical disturbance info of PMU
        \item   locate power system event,
        \item   to select the best set of features of the disturbance types in the time-frequency domain,
        \item   discrete samples of collected PMU data,
        \item   assess the power system disturbance by using wide-area post disturbance records
        to identify events and characterize their features.
            \end{enumerate}
            &   \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
            \item   PMU
            \item   PMU and smart meter 30-120 times per sec
                \end{enumerate}
                &   &   \\
“A Novel Event Detection Method Using PMU Data with High Precision” by Mingjian Cui, Jianhui Wang, Jin Tan, Anthony R. Florita, and  Yingchen Zhang, published in IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON POWER SYSTEMS, 2018
    &   This paper develops a new method of event detection using dynamic programming-based SDT (DPSDT) and compares it with the Wavelet-based event detection (WED) technique. It gives the complete algorithm of the DPSDT technique and compares various events it could detect with sufficient graphs and figures.
        &   \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
        \item   To reduce dimensionality of original streaming PMU data, islanding detection,
        \item   compress critical disturbance info of PMU
        \item   locate power system event,
        \item   to select the best set of features of the disturbance types in the time-frequency domain,
        \item   discrete samples of collected PMU data,
        \item   assess the power system disturbance by using wide-area post disturbance records
        to identify events and characterize their features.
            \end{enumerate}
            &   \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
            \item   PMU
            \item   PMU and smart meter 30-120 times per sec
                \end{enumerate}
                &   &   \\
“A Novel Event Detection Method Using PMU Data with High Precision” by Mingjian Cui, Jianhui Wang, Jin Tan, Anthony R. Florita, and  Yingchen Zhang, published in IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON POWER SYSTEMS, 2018
    &   This paper develops a new method of event detection using dynamic programming-based SDT (DPSDT) and compares it with the Wavelet-based event detection (WED) technique. It gives the complete algorithm of the DPSDT technique and compares various events it could detect with sufficient graphs and figures.
        &   \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
        \item   To reduce dimensionality of original streaming PMU data, islanding detection,
        \item   compress critical disturbance info of PMU
        \item   locate power system event,
        \item   to select the best set of features of the disturbance types in the time-frequency domain,
        \item   discrete samples of collected PMU data,
        \item   assess the power system disturbance by using wide-area post disturbance records
        to identify events and characterize their features.
            \end{enumerate}
            &   \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
            \item   PMU
            \item   PMU and smart meter 30-120 times per sec
                \end{enumerate}
                &   &   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

- Content of the first row is repeated four times that it  is visible how the table is spread over two pages.
- As you can see, in table is used `\small` font size that cells content is better filled. With this font size the table is still easy to read, however, you can preserve normal font size (12pt) by remove `\small` option from code line

```
 cells   = {font=\small\linespread{0.84}\selectfont}
```

In this case table will looks as follows:

[image]