# I want this table to fit the entire page in lateX

Tags: tables, beamer, longtable, presentations

I want this table to fit the entire page of the document in landscape mode. I don't understand how it is leaving the blank area below in the page.

Also, if someone can suggest how do we put this in the PPT format?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[table, svgnames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[a4paper, landscape, margin=1cm,]{geometry}

\usepackage{makecell, cellspace, caption}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{2pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\usepackage{enumitem,ragged2e}
\newlist{myenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenumerate,1]{label=\alph*.,nosep,wide=0pt,
          before={\begin{minipage}{\hsize}\RaggedRight},
          after={\end{minipage}}}

\begin{document}
       
\begin{longtable}{| L{5cm} | L{4cm} | L{5cm} | L{2.5cm} | L{2cm} | L{2cm} |}
\hline
\rowcolor{Gainsboro!60}
\makecell{Source of \\ information \\ (reference) } & 
\makecell{Method of  \\ identification} & 
\makecell{The consumer’s strengths \\ to address these issues.} & 
\makecell{Consumer \\ and Nursing \\ Interventions} & 
\makecell{Person/s \\ Responsible} & 
\makecell{Timeframe}\\
\hline
\endhead

“A Novel Event Detection Method Using PMU Data with High Precision,” by Mingjian Cui, Jianhui Wang, Jin Tan, Anthony R. Florita, and Yingchen Zhang, published in IEEE Transactions on Power Systems, 2018

& This paper develops a new method of event detection using dynamic programming-based SDT (DPSDT) and compares it with the Wavelet-based event detection (WED) technique. It gives the complete algorithm of the DPSDT technique and compares various events it could detect with sufficient graphs and figures.

& \begin{myenumerate}
\item \strut To reduce dimensionality of original streaming PMU data, islanding detection,
\item compress critical disturbance info of PMU 
\item locate power system event, 
\item to select the best set of features of the disturbance types in the time-frequency domain, 
\item discrete samples of collected PMU data, 
\item assess the power system disturbance by using wide-area post disturbance records to identify events and characterize their features.\strut
\end{myenumerate}

 & 1.~PMU

   2.~PMU and smart meter,
   & 30--120 times per sec
 & 
\\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

For the usecase output reference:
[image]

Comment: What is "PPT format"? PowerPoint, maybe? And why did you set the 'beamer' tag yet employ not the `beamer` but the `article` document class? Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

For writing of your table you may consider the `tabularray` package and `X` columns types which will force table that it width  will be equal to text width in landscape page orientation :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, landscape, 
            margin=1cm, includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[table, svgnames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}

\usepackage{enumitem} % create a bespoke list env.
\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenum,1]{nosep=0pt, itemsep=2pt,
                    wide=0pt,
                    label=\textbf{\alph*.},
                    after=\end{minipage},
                    before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}\RaggedRight}
                  }

\begin{document}
    \begingroup
    \DefTblrTemplate{firsthead, middlehead,lasthead}{default}{} % <---
    \DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}{\scriptsize\textit{Continued on the next page}}
\begin{longtblr}[
                ]{hlines, vlines,
                  colspec = {*{2}{X[2,j]} X[3,l] *{3}{X[l]}},
                  rowhead = 1,
                  row{1}  = {bg=Gainsboro!60, c, m},
                  measure = vbox
                 }
Source of information (reference)
    & Method of identification
        & The consumer’s strengths to address these issues.
            & Consumer and Nursing Interventions
                & Person/s Responsible
                    & Timeframe             \\
“A Novel Event Detection Method Using PMU Data with High Precision,” by Mingjian Cui, Jianhui Wang, Jin Tan, Anthony R. Florita, and Yingchen Zhang, published in IEEE Transactions on Power Systems, 2018
    &   This paper develops a new method of event detection using dynamic programming-based SDT (DPSDT) and compares it with the Wavelet-based event detection (WED) technique. It gives the complete algorithm of the DPSDT technique and compares various events it could detect with sufficient graphs and figures.
        &   \begin{tabenum}
        \item   reduce dimensionality of original streaming PMU data, islanding detection,
        \item compress critical disturbance info of PMU
        \item locate power system event,
        \item select the best set of features of the disturbance types in the time-frequency domain,
        \item collect discrete samples of PMU data,
        \item assess the power system disturbance by using wide-area post disturbance records to identify events and characterize their features.
            \end{tabenum}
            &   \begin{tabenum}[label=\arabic*.]
            \item   PMU
            \item   PMU and smart meter,
                \end{tabenum}
                & 30--120 times per sec
                    &               \\
“A Novel Event Detection Method Using PMU Data with High Precision,” by Mingjian Cui, Jianhui Wang, Jin Tan, Anthony R. Florita, and Yingchen Zhang, published in IEEE Transactions on Power Systems, 2018
    &   This paper develops a new method of event detection using dynamic programming-based SDT (DPSDT) and compares it with the Wavelet-based event detection (WED) technique. It gives the complete algorithm of the DPSDT technique and compares various events it could detect with sufficient graphs and figures.
        &   \begin{tabenum}
        \item   reduce dimensionality of original streaming PMU data, islanding detection,
        \item compress critical disturbance info of PMU
        \item locate power system event,
        \item select the best set of features of the disturbance types in the time-frequency domain,
        \item collect discrete samples of PMU data,
        \item assess the power system disturbance by using wide-area post disturbance records to identify events and characterize their features.
            \end{tabenum}
            &   \begin{tabenum}[label=\arabic*.]
            \item   PMU
            \item   PMU and smart meter,
                \end{tabenum}
                & 30--120 times per sec
                    &               \\
“A Novel Event Detection Method Using PMU Data with High Precision,” by Mingjian Cui, Jianhui Wang, Jin Tan, Anthony R. Florita, and Yingchen Zhang, published in IEEE Transactions on Power Systems, 2018
    &   This paper develops a new method of event detection using dynamic programming-based SDT (DPSDT) and compares it with the Wavelet-based event detection (WED) technique. It gives the complete algorithm of the DPSDT technique and compares various events it could detect with sufficient graphs and figures.
        &   \begin{tabenum}
        \item   reduce dimensionality of original streaming PMU data, islanding detection,
        \item compress critical disturbance info of PMU
        \item locate power system event,
        \item select the best set of features of the disturbance types in the time-frequency domain,
        \item collect discrete samples of PMU data,
        \item assess the power system disturbance by using wide-area post disturbance records to identify events and characterize their features.
            \end{tabenum}
            &   \begin{tabenum}[label=\arabic*.]
            \item   PMU
            \item   PMU and smart meter,
                \end{tabenum}
                & 30--120 times per sec
                    &               \\
“A Novel Event Detection Method Using PMU Data with High Precision,” by Mingjian Cui, Jianhui Wang, Jin Tan, Anthony R. Florita, and Yingchen Zhang, published in IEEE Transactions on Power Systems, 2018
    &   This paper develops a new method of event detection using dynamic programming-based SDT (DPSDT) and compares it with the Wavelet-based event detection (WED) technique. It gives the complete algorithm of the DPSDT technique and compares various events it could detect with sufficient graphs and figures.
        &   \begin{tabenum}
        \item   reduce dimensionality of original streaming PMU data, islanding detection,
        \item compress critical disturbance info of PMU
        \item locate power system event,
        \item select the best set of features of the disturbance types in the time-frequency domain,
        \item collect discrete samples of PMU data,
        \item assess the power system disturbance by using wide-area post disturbance records to identify events and characterize their features.
            \end{tabenum}
            &   \begin{tabenum}[label=\arabic*.]
            \item   PMU
            \item   PMU and smart meter,
                \end{tabenum}
                & 30--120 times per sec
                    &               \\
\end{longtblr}
    \endgroup
\end{document}
```

In MWE are repeated for table body that can be seen how would long table looks. In MWE is considered, that table hasn't printed caption. However, table counter is still incremented.

[image]

In the case, that caption will be added, than the document preamble had to be changed to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, landscape, 
            margin=1cm, includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[table, svgnames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}

\usepackage{enumitem} % create a bespoke list env.
\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenum,1]{nosep=0pt, itemsep=2pt,
                    wide=0pt,
                    label=\textbf{\alph*.},
                    after=\end{minipage},
                    before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}\RaggedRight}
                  }

\begin{longtblr}[
    caption={My long table ...},
      label={tab:???}
                ]{hlines, vlines,
                  colspec = {*{2}{X[2,j]} X[3,l] *{3}{X[l]}},
                  rowhead = 1,
                  row{1}  = {bg=Gainsboro!60, c, m},
                  measure = vbox
                 }
```

In this case the caption on the next ae looks as follows:

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with a calculation of the amount of horizontal space that's available for the table. You're using A4 paper in landscape format, with 1.0cm margins. Since the width of the paper is 29.7cm, the width of text block is `29.7cm-2.0cm=27.7cm`. Your table contains 6 columns -- with `\tabcolsep` (6pt) of whitespace padding on each side -- and 7 vertical lines -- of width `\arrayrulesep` (0.4pt); `12*6.0pt+7*0.4pt=74.8pt=2.63cm`. (Aside: `1pt=0.035146cm`.) The *usable* width of all 6 columns combined is therefore `27.7cm-2.63cm=25.07cm`. Let's round this to 25cm for now.

Your code contains the instruction

```
\begin{longtable}{| L{5cm} | L{4cm} | L{5cm} | L{2.5cm} | L{2cm} | L{2cm} |}
```

Summing the six widths gives 20.5cm; that's 4.5cm *less* than the maximally available width of 25cm.

I take it that your objective is to increase some or all of the columns widths so that the *sum* amounts to 25cm. I suggest that you not increase all (usable) column widths linearly. Instead, I'd widen the third column the most, since that's where by far the most of the information contained in the table appears to be located. I'd also widen the second column, as well as 5th column -- just slightly, say by 0.5cm, since its header is currently a bit clipped.

I'd also switch from the `m` to the `p` column type in the definition of the `L` column type.

Summing up, I'd use an instruction such as

```
\begin{longtable}{| L{5cm} | L{5cm} | L{8.07cm} | L{2.5cm} | L{2.5cm} | L{2cm} |}
```

(Observe that I've added the `0.07cm` back in, and assigned it to the 3rd column.)

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[table, svgnames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[a4paper, landscape, margin=1cm, includefoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{makecell, cellspace, caption}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{2pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}

\usepackage{array} % for '\newcolumntype' and '\extrarowheight' macros
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}} % 'p', not 'm'
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

\usepackage{enumitem,ragged2e} % create a bespoke list env.
\newlist{myenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenumerate,1]{label=\alph*.,nosep,wide=0pt,
          before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}\RaggedRight},
          after={\end{minipage}}}

\begin{document}
       
\begin{longtable}{| L{5cm} | L{5cm} | L{8.07cm} | L{2.5cm} | L{2.5cm} | L{2cm} |}
\hline
\rowcolor{Gainsboro!60}
\makecell{Source of \\ information \\ (reference) } & 
\makecell{Method of  \\ identification} & 
\makecell{The consumer’s strengths \\ to address these issues.} & 
\makecell{Consumer \\ and Nursing \\ Interventions} & 
\makecell{Person/s \\ Responsible} & 
\makecell{Timeframe}\\
\hline
\endhead

\hline
\endlastfoot

“A Novel Event Detection Method Using PMU Data with High Precision,” by Mingjian Cui, Jianhui Wang, Jin Tan, Anthony R. Florita, and Yingchen Zhang, published in IEEE Transactions on Power Systems, 2018

& This paper develops a new method of event detection using dynamic programming-based SDT (DPSDT) and compares it with the Wavelet-based event detection (WED) technique. It gives the complete algorithm of the DPSDT technique and compares various events it could detect with sufficient graphs and figures.

& \begin{myenumerate}
\item \strut reduce dimensionality of original streaming PMU data, islanding detection,
\item compress critical disturbance info of PMU 
\item locate power system event, 
\item select the best set of features of the disturbance types in the time-frequency domain, 
\item collect discrete samples of PMU data, 
\item assess the power system disturbance by using wide-area post disturbance records to identify events and characterize their features.
\end{myenumerate}

 & 1.~PMU

   2.~PMU and smart meter,
 & 30--120 times per sec
 & 
\\

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```